# AWS Lambda Node.js runtime version upgrade

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Some of our lambda functions have Node.js runtime version 10 and some others are on runtime version 14.

As Node.js version 14 will be coming to End of life in November 2023 and AWS recommends to upgrade the runtime version to v18, I wanted to know whether Node 18 is backward compatible until Node v10.

In other words, if I just edit the runtime version of the lambda functions to Node.js v18, should I expect that it might not run because of compatibility issues?

Comment: Why don't you _test them_ in the version of Node you're planning to move to?

Comment: Well, there you go.